# Unable to delete row in Angular JS

Tags: angularjs

I am trying to delete a row in Angular JS using web service but unable to do it. Here is my code:script.js

```
 $scope.DeleteEmployee = function (EID) {
          var data = $.param({
              EID: $scope.EmpId
          });
          var config = {
              headers: {
                  'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=utf-8'
              }
          }
          $http.post("EmpWebService.asmx/DeleteEmployee", EID, config)
          .then(function (response) {
              alert("Deleted successfully.");
              $scope.getEmployee();
          });

      }
```

employee.aspx

```
  <td>
<a href="#" ng-click="DeleteEmployee(employee.EmpId)">Delete</a>
   </td>
```

I am getting employee id in script.js as EID but after debugging by F12 this error is coming
 http://localhost:55735/EmpWebService.asmx/DeleteEmployee 500 (Internal Server Error)

Comment: Can you post more details about the error ? Like the stack trace

Comment: I think your problem is not related to AngularJS, but to your server implementation. Please check what kind of parameters your send to your server (still F12), the server response body if any.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Frame your request like this:

```
$http({
  method: "POST",
  url: 'EmpWebService.asmx/DeleteEmployee',
  data: {Id: EID},
  headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=utf-8'}
})
.then(function(reponse){...});
```

Please note that `Id` should be the name of the parameter expected in your route if it is not then please change the code accordingly

Answer (score 0):

It seems you have a typo, you should rather call `$http.post` with `data`:

```
$http.post("EmpWebService.asmx/DeleteEmployee", data, config)
```

instead of :

```
$http.post("EmpWebService.asmx/DeleteEmployee", EID, config)
```

Comment: i had already used data instead of EID. but data has blank value so I passed EID.

Comment: I think you should pass `data` with data built that way: `var data = $.param({ "EID": EID});`. I suppose that server side is expecting `"EID"` as parameter name.

Comment: when debugging by F12 i found that controller terminates from the line $http.post("EmpWebService.asmx/DeleteEmployee", data, config)

Comment: You should definetely debug on the server side and see if the web service is really getting the expected ID. In other terms, debug to see why it is returning HTTP 500 error.